# How to contour a 2D element mesh in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, contourf

I'm trying to contour the output for some solution of groundwater diffusion in 2D finite element triangular mesh.

This is the code which I used:

```
%% 3d Surface plot of Ground water Head
tri= delaunay(x,y);
trisurf(tri,x,y,h);

title('Head Distribution');
xlabel('Distance along the X axis(m)');
ylabel('Distance along the Y axis(m)');
zlabel('Head(m)');
colorbar eastoutside;
```

This is the figure which is not working:

```
figure(2)
[c,hh] = contourf(tri,x,y,h,18); 
clabel(c,hh)
title('Tricontour')
```

[image: plot for figure one]

Comment: There is no MATLAB inbuilt for tetrahedra contours. You'd need to interpolate into a regular grid and use `contour` or use the various available codes in the Mathworks FEX

Comment: It is not tetrahedra this is a simple triangular element, but the shape of the domain R2 is tetrahedra

Comment: Sorry, I meant trianglulation, not tetrahedra.